# Low-level operations with Appstats in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, appstats

After GAE's new pricing I'm having serious difficulties in optimizing my entities. I'm aware of the high-level to low-level operations conversion rules and I'm using Appstats to observe the number of puts, deletes, queries, etc.
The problem is that I'm billed by low-level operations and I can't see them directly at Appstats. It would be very nice if I could change my entity and see the impact in the number of low-level operations, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's currently no way to get this information in appstats.